# Get identifying server information when running PHP scripts with CRON

Tags: php, cron

I've got a PHP script that I want to run through cron.  It should load different configuration information depending on if the script is running on my local server, the QA server, or the production server.  The problem is that when the script is run through cron, it doesn't have any of the identifying $_SERVER information that I use to figure out which environment the script is running on.

The only thing I could think of was to have the cron job itself attach a parameter to the script, but I was hoping there was a better way where I wouldn't have to do that.  Is there any other way to identify which server the script resides on when running it from cron?

Thanks.

Comment: How are the servers different? Check on IP-address, check for existence of a path, contents of a file...

Comment: Can't use gethostname(), because I'm on PHP 5.2.  And I'm not sure how to get the IP address without the $_SERVER variables.  Otherwise, the servers are set up with the same code, so I could do something like check for a path, but I'd have to insert it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the problem the next way: pass to script environment variables.

In case of .htaccess / httpd.conf:
`SetEnv SITE_NAME x1`

In case of cron (run a script):

```
#!/bin/bash
export SITE_NAME=x1;
php /path
```

In both cases PHP-code to get this environment variable is: `getenv('SITE_NAME');`

x1 — is an example site name.

Comment: That seems like a great solution, but how permanent are those environment variables?  If the box is reset, do they disappear?

Comment: The variables in .htaccess files or server configs (like httpd.conf) is absolutely permanent. In bash script the variable is set every runtime before PHP script is executed. You just have to run shell-script from cron (not a direct php call). So the solution is "permanent" and works for me properly for a long time.

Comment: Oh wait, I see now.  The script I run would add the variable right before it runs the script.  That's perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

getenv('COMPUTERNAME') will return the computer name it is running on...

However, if your script does different things in production to test, how do you know that it is correct in production?

Comment: That function doesn't return anything when I try it.  And the script doesn't do anything different, it just has different configuration variables.  For example, the database connection information is different.

Comment: Requested solution can be used to select proper configuration file (ex. database connection settings). It not seems to be bad practice. I use this techniques to detect site name, because I have different sites running on one copy of code (using virtual hosts on dedicated server).